# Trying to use X command to run UNIX commands from SAS EG

Tags: unix, sas

Here are the steps I followed ....
1)Created a shell script /fbrms01/dev/projects/Err_check.sh with following code in it....

```
Y=`date +'%Y'`
  M=`date +'%m'`
  D=`date +'%d'`
  today=$Y.$M.$D
  echo $today
  ls -l /fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/*_"$today"*.log | xargs grep "ERROR:" >         /fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/log_error.dat
```

2)Ran shell script on UNIX and it worked fine and created .dat file with exactly what I need.

```
$sh Err_check.sh
```

3)Ran that shell script on SAS using X command...Tried both

```
X '/fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/sh Err_check.sh';
  X 'sh Err_check.sh';
```

But it is not creating the .dat file.... 
Any idea where I'm doing mistake....
Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Are you confident you have XCMD option and not NOXCMD set by your sysadmin?  Also, you may want to consider that SAS executing a shell script will presumably be in a different environment and with a different user than you executing the same shell script.

Comment: Hi Joe,I did used X command before and it worked...Is that mean XCMD option was set rite?Both UNIX and SAS are logged in using same user.

Comment: Presumably.  Are you sure that SAS is running x commands as that user, though?  That seems like one of the most likely issues.  You could also have some problem with quoting, but running the shell script like you did should avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*STEP1:Created a .sh file with following code on unix 
    Y=`date +'%Y'`
    M=`date +'%m'`
    D=`date +'%d'`
    today=$Y.$M.$D
    ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_*_"$today"_*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:" >> /fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/log_error.dat*/

/*STEP2:Run the shell script using X command*/
X 'sh /fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/log_error.sh';
```